# Color guessing in Javascript repeatedly gives "does not recognize color" error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple color guessing game with JavaScript, but the program's code is not working right. It's stuck on the first condition and returns the same alert ("Sorry, I don't recognize your color. Please try again.") even though I created other conditions to recognize different user inputs and show different alert messages. The program is also supposed to change the background color of the html page to the correct color when the guess input matches the random color generated by the first part of the program.

Here's the code:

```
 var target;
 var color = ["blue", "green", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"];
 var guess_input_text;
 var guess_input;
 var finished = false;
 var guesses = 0;

 function do_game() {

   var random_color = color[Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];
   target = random_color;

   while (!finished) {
     guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors: "+
                           "blue, green, orange, red, white, yellow. " +
                           "What color am I thinking of?");
     guess_input = parseInt(guess_input_text);
     guesses += 1;
     finished = check_guess();
   }

 }

 function check_guess() {

     if (guess_input != color) {
       alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color. " +
             "Please try again.");
       return false;
     }
     if (guess_input > target) {
       alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct! " +
             "Hint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine. " +
             "Please try again.");
       return false;
     }
     if (guess_input < target) {
       alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct! " +
             "Hint: your color is alphabetically lower than mine. " +
             "Please try again.");
       return false;
     }
     if (guess_input == target) {
     myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     myBody.style.background = "target" ;
       alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color! " +
             "It took you " + guesses + "guesses to finish the game. " +
             "You can see the color in the background.");
       return true;
     }

 }
```

I wanted to post the question to see if anyone has a solution I could use to fix the program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are prompting the user fro some string, you convert it to an integer (probably `NaN`) and then you compare it with an array. Of course they are different.

Comment: Just a tip for further coding: Give your functions arguments because it's a bad practice to rely on global variables. Functions should rely only on arguments those are given while executed ;)

Answer (score 1):

I saw some error in your code.

- Don't need to use `parseInt(guess_input_text)` because input is not a number.
- `if (guess_input != color) {` this is not correct because color is an `Array`; here you need to check `guess_input` is exists in that `color` `Array` or not.

Here is the Solution. Have a look on my code :-

```
        var target;
        var color = ["blue", "cyan", "gray", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"].sort();
        var guess_input_text;
        var guess_input;
        var finished = false;
        var guesses = 0;

        function do_game() {

            var random_color = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)]; // Get a Random value from array
            target = random_color.toLowerCase();
            while (!finished) {
                guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:- \n\n" + 
                                           color.join(", ") + 
                                          ".\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?");
                guess_input = guess_input_text.toLowerCase();
                guesses += 1;
                finished = check_guess();
            }

        }

        function check_guess() {

            if (color.indexOf(guess_input) === -1) {
                alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color. \n\n" +
                      "Please try again.");
                return false;
            }
            if (guess_input > target) {
                alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct! \n\n" +
                      "Hint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine. \n\n" +
                      "Please try again.");
                return false;
            }
            if (guess_input < target) {
                alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct! \n\n" +
                      "Hint: your color is alphabetically lower than mine. \n\n" +
                      "Please try again.");
                return false;
            }
            if (guess_input === target) {

                myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                myBody.style.background = target;

                alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color! \n\n" +
                      "It took you " + guesses + " guesses to finish the game. \n\n" +
                      "You can see the color in the background.");
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Please check it out! and If you have any problem let me know. Hope everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
if (guess_input != color)
```

color is an Array.  Instead of checking for equality to the array as a whole, you need to go through the elements in the array and make sure guess_input isn't one of those elements.

You are also assuming guess_input_text is an integer, and initializing guess_input as an integer:

```
guess_input = parseInt(guess_input_text);
```

If you intend to compare the user's answer to a string (the name of the color), of course you can't expect the user's answer to be an integer.

Comment: `guess_input` is `parseInt(prompt())`. And `color` array contains no integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (guess_input_text !== color) {
```

this should match assuming the prompt answer is a string.